# Cannot run e2e tests with a new angular/cli app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, selenium, protractor

I just created a new angular/cli app and tried to run the e2e tests and got this bunch of errors:

```
 npm run e2e                                                                                                                                                                                

 angular-e2e-tutorial@0.0.0 e2e D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial                                                                                             
 ng e2e                                                                                                                                                                                     

* Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **                                                                            

ate: 2019-01-22T18:45:07.651Z                                                                                                                                                               
ash: dfdee1e6d8be823b0847                                                                                                                                                                   
ime: 12512ms                                                                                                                                                                                
hunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 40.3 kB [initial] [rendered]                                                                                                                        
hunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]                                                                                                     
hunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]                                                                                                              
hunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.8 kB [initial] [rendered]                                                                                                                
hunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.01 MB [initial] [rendered]                                                                                                                
20:45:07] I/config_source - curl -oD:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https
chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/                                                                                                                                                        
 ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.                                                                                                                                                              
20:45:09] I/update - chromedriver: file exists D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_
5.zip                                                                                                                                                                                       
20:45:09] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.45.zip                                                                                                                          
20:45:09] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.45.exe up to date                                                                                                                         
20:45:10] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver                                                                                                                                     
20:45:10] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...                                                                                                                                         

evTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53398/devtools/browser/3440c283-44ff-44de-881f-d75109c1bf41                                                                                             
20:46:13] E/launcher - unknown error: unable to discover open pages                                                                                                                         
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)                                                                   
20:46:13] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: unable to discover open pages                                                                                                         
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)                                                                   
   at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)              
   at parseHttpResponse (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)                        
   at doSend.then.response (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)                     
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)                                                                                                                            
rom: Task: WebDriver.createSession()                                                                                                                                                        
   at Function.createSession (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)              
   at Function.createSession (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)                     
   at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)                                   
   at Runner.createBrowser (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)                                                 
   at q.then.then (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29)                                                          
   at _fulfilled (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)                                                                               
   at D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30                                                                                            
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)                                                          
   at D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49                                                                                            
   at runSingle (D:\Projects\Playground\angular-e2e-testing\angular-e2e-tutorial\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)                                                                                
20:46:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199                                                                                                                                   
n unexpected error occurred: undefined                                                                                                                                                      
pm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using protractor and not directly selenium.